# Could someone write a query for finding Revival candidates?

Tags: support, data-explorer, revival-badge

I don't have a Revival badge yet, and thinking that I'm missing out on something SE wants to encourage, I decided to try for one.  However, I found that it is not easy even to find a candidate for Revival, let alone a question that needs a better answer.  So could someone write a query that filters out all questions except those which are >30 days old *and* with no answers that have 2 score or more?

Edit: I am an [ELU user](https://english.stackexchange.com/users/10041/dr65), if that makes a difference.

Edit: I asked this [on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7276238/812538), and got a response, resulting in [this query](https://data.stackexchange.com/english/s/1812/revival-badge-candidates).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Here's the [data-explorer](/questions/tagged/data-explorer) query you asked for:

[Revival candidate question finder](https://data.stackexchange.com/english/s/1813/revival-candidate-question-finder)

The query allows filtering by question score and by tag(s).  Note that the tag separating characters vary from SE site DB to SE site DB (bug?).

It "currently" shows 231 eligible questions (with score >= -5).

Keep in mind that the SEDE lags about a week from live data, but that probably only matters for the "freshest" questions.

Comment: I can't get it to work without entering tags, which I don't want to do.  Am I missing something?

Comment: Just enter a single space instead of the tags, I tested it, and it works fine that way.    Alternatively, enter a single underscore (`_`).   Here is a direct [link to the query with `minScore = 0`, and all tags allowed](http://data.stackexchange.com/english/s/1813/revival-candidate-question-finder?MinQscore=0&DesiredTags=_).

Comment: Also, the query I was given on SO gives 559 results.  Why does yours give only 230?

Comment: The query you were given for [this SO question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/7276238/331508) returns questions that already have accepted answers!   I'm not sure if you can get the revival badge at all on such questions, but it seems a lot less likely -- since the Q has already been "resolved".

Comment: OK, I see.  I think you can get the badge on such questions; still, it *is* more likely to get it if you're not answering something that has already accepted an answer.  Thanks!

Answer (score 6):

Here's your "query": https://stackoverflow.com/unanswered/tagged/?tab=newest

Just scroll to the bottom and pick [page 1000](https://stackoverflow.com/unanswered/tagged/?page=1000&tab=newest). If that's not far enough back, try 1100, 1500, &c.

EDIT:
Whoops, I missed that the badge requires no answers with >1 score, rather than >=1 score. The unanswered page will still work, but you'll miss out on some questions that do qualify. I will try to remember to write a query later. Be advised that any query will also be imperfect, since the data dumps are static and old.

Comment: I edited my question - I am an ELU user, and ELU is a very close site.  (E.g. no one has Tumbleweed, Tenacious, or Unsung Hero)  So it's hard to find questions that need revival.

Comment: Well, that's even easier, then. There are only [two questions that have no answers with >1 score](http://english.stackexchange.com/unanswered/tagged/?tab=newest), and both were asked less than 30 days ago.

Comment: No: I meant the *answers* did not have >1 score.  I'm talking about the Revival badge here.

Comment: That part, I did get. That's what the unanswered page does. From its description: "questions with __no upvoted answers__" (emphasis original). Note that I gave you a link with a date sort, not a votes sort.

Comment: But *not >1* means not *2 or more*.  I didn't say no upvoted answers.  I said no answers that have 2 or more votes.

Comment: I already addressed that in my most recent edit by saying "you'll miss out on some questions that do qualify." Any question that has no upvoted answers necessarily has no answers with score of two or more, though.

Comment: But applied to ELU, your (unanswered tab) method causes me to miss out on *all* qualifying questions.  That's why I asked for a query.

Comment: Yes, I already acknowledged that. I don't know what else there is to say.

Comment: So should I wait until you can write one?

Comment: Well, _someone_ needs to write one. It doesn't have to be me. This is not just a valid Meta question, it's also a programming (well, SQL) question. You could ask on Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 2):

Note that you can get pretty close using just the site's search capabilities.

The basic part of the search would be `is:question closed:no created:31d`.

You could filter out questions with accepted answers using `hasaccepted:no`.

You could get questions with `N` or fewer answers with `answers:..N`.

If you really wanted to find questions with no answers with score of 2 or more, then yes, you'd need to use SEDE.

[Here's a query I wrote](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/1685268/revival-badge-candidates?ResultCount=100&MinQScore=0&Tag=javascript)

```sql
SELECT TOP ##ResultCount:int?100##
  MAX(Q.Id) AS [Post Link],
  MAX(Q.Score),
  --MAX(Q.Title),
  MAX(Q.Tags),
  --MAX(Q.Body),
  MAX(Q.CreationDate),
  COUNT(A.Id) AS AnswerCount
FROM Posts Q
JOIN Posts A ON A.ParentId = Q.Id
WHERE
  Q.PostTypeId = 1
  AND Q.ClosedDate IS NULL
  AND Q.Score >= ##MinQScore:int?0##
  AND Q.CreationDate < GETDATE() - DAY(30)
  AND Q.Tags LIKE '%<'##Tag:string?javascript##'>%'
GROUP BY Q.Id
HAVING MAX(A.Score) < 2
ORDER BY MAX(Q.Id) DESC
```

It's kind of slow (sorry). Maybe someone who knows better than me will see this and give some feedback.